# How can I change DataStudio default display in charts when I don't select anything in the drop-down control filter?

Tags: looker-studio

I create drop-down list(Q1,Q2,Q3) to filter the charts and tables. If I don't select anything in the drop-down list, the charts and tables will automatically show everything(Q1,Q2,Q3) -- how can I change the default value charts and tables that are displaying to Q1's value only?

To be more specific, if I don't select anything in the drop-down list, the charts and tables will show Q1's results; if I select Q2 in the drop-down list, the charts and tables will show Q2's result.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3bCnd.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

Kindly look for `default selection` at the **filter property panel**, as circled in screenshot below.

[image: imgage]

For example, when I enter "US" as the default selection, the entire dashboard is filtered to US by default. However, the user can still look for other selections if they are interested on other available country.

Do note the data here is dummy data, not the real-world data.

If you're interested to check out the dashboard to see what's the expected output, here is the [link](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/d59e0c50-0287-4f05-b7c1-60743e1130e5/page/Hem6B)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!  Is it possible to show the US result in the table as default when I don't select anything in the "country" drop down filter?

Comment: Sure you can :) 


Look for the default selection, key in "US" in there, and you're good to go!

Comment: Hi Leahjl, I've edited the answer to make it more comprehensive, hope it helps

Comment: I think what the OP is asking about is a bug that seems to be happening with Google DS. When a control is set to single select then one of the options should always be selected. But DS is allowing you to unselect them all, in which case it uses all values in the set.